# How to disable Okular from following links?

Tags: okular

Okular fetches and opens content when (inadvertently) clicking on links. I tend to bleach my PDF files before I open them, and would like to disable Okular from blindly opening PDFs (or any other content on the other side of a link).

Is this possible?

**How to disable Okular from following links when clicking on the linked text?**

Answer (score -2):

Okular 1.10.3 on Manjaro does not open any links automatically, not even by clicking on the linking strings. Text selection has to be enabled, the string has to be selected and open via context menu.

Maybe try selecting Browse instead of Text Selection.

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04 Okular opens embedded links when clicking on the linked text. This behavior is what I am asking for help in halting. Asserting that this behavior does not exist makes for a poor answer.